# Using Javascript spread operator inside a constant

Tags: javascript

Reframing the original question as it created confusion -

The following code -

```
var BoldText = ''

const currentTheme = {
  BoldText: {
    color: 'black' 
  },
  Text:{ ...BoldText, fontSize:10 }
}
```

Produces this output -

```
console.log(currentTheme.Text)
VM254:1 {fontSize: 10}
```

Whereas I expect this to produce this output -

```
{color:'black', fontSize: 10}
```

Can anyone please help me understand why?

Comment: Why spread? Sounds like you might want `text:{ BoldText }`

Comment: updated the question.... I want to add few more values other than inheriting the existing ones as well. That's why spreading.

Comment: `{ ...{BoldText},fontSize:10}` is this supposed to be `{ ...BoldText,fontSize:10}` (spread `BoldText`) ?

Comment: What sort of value do you expect to be in `BoldText`? A primitive, array or object? If you could show some concrete examples of what you want, that would be great

Comment: @VLAZ I tried that already.... did not work

Comment: @Phil its an object

Comment: @ShibasisSengupta please edit your question with some examples of the result you want

Comment: @ShibasisSengupta what is the expected outcome here? Also, what does `BoldText` contain?

Comment: After OP's update - so, when you define `BoldText` as an empty object, you now get an empty object? That *is* what you are setting it as. I'm still confused as to what the problem is here - the code does exactly what you've told it to. What *should* it do instead?

Comment: Is there some confusion around the request for examples? Please show, given a real example of a `BoldText` object, what the resulting `currentTheme` should look like.

Comment: @Phil added... please see

Comment: No really, here's what you do. You say _"If I have this variable `var BoldText = { /* insert real code here */ }`, then I want the **entire `currentTheme` variable** to look like this..."_ and then you show the whole object **exactly how you want it to look**

Comment: currentTheme is an object, which has two objects inside it - 'BoldText' and "Text". I want Text to inherit the properties of 'BoldText', plus add more properties to it

Comment: I am literally telling you what to write in your question so you can get helpful answers. Is there a problem with the instructions?

Comment: @Phil yes...what's more explanation this question needs than its already there?

Comment: You have two answers that supposedly aren't correct, a 15-long comment chain, one downvote and two close votes for _"Unclear what you're asking"_ so you tell me, based on that feedback do you think there's enough information in the question or not?

Comment: `var BoldText` is *completely* unrelated to the property in `currentTheme = { BoldText: { color: 'black' } }`. It seems like you expect the two to be the same thing and setting the property also sets the variable. If you do want them to be the same, you have to invert it and set `var BoldText` to be an object, then use it when you're creating `currentTheme`. Look at [**lumio**'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58375952/using-javascript-spread-operator-inside-a-constant/#58376027)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example `var BoldText` is not set and therefore `undefined`. The `BoldText` within `currentTheme` is not yet declared when you want to call it and would cause an error.

**Instead you could define `BoldText` outside and then use it within `currentTheme` multiple times.**

```js
const BoldText = {
  color: 'black',
};

const currentTheme = {
  BoldText,
  text: {
    ...BoldText,  // use content of BoldText
    fontSize: 10, // and add more to it.
  }
}

console.log( currentTheme.text ); // Now the content of `BoldText` is within `currentTheme.text`
```

However, spreading `BoldText` doesn't really make sense, unless if `BoldText` itself is an object and you want to do a shallow clone.

Comment: OP has a property in `currentTheme` named `BoldText` that is not a reference to the `BoldText` variable so I think your answer might be a little off-the-mark

Comment: Could be. It looked to me - although I make assumptions here - that OP wanted to reuse `currentTheme.BoldText` in the first place.

Comment: Yes, the question is still quite confusing

Comment: @lumio thanks but this is not what I am looking for... I know this would work. But I wanted to reuse inside 'currentTheme'

Comment: @ShibasisSengupta ah, then removing the brackets (`{ }`) around `BoldText` should work. I updated my answer.

Comment: Based on the revised question, this seems to be the correct answer. OP does seem to want all of `BoldText` instances to be the same, so this requires `const BoldText` to be set as whatever the properties in the object are required to be.

Comment: Accept it... this is the closest as it can get to what I am trying to do... my approach was wrong... sorry it has been a long day

Comment: @ShibasisSengupta no worries :) we all were and will be in the same situation

Answer (score 1):

You have declared the variable "BoldText" but never defined it. That is why it shows undefined.
Also there is a syntactical error in spread operator.

Have a look at the below code

```
var BoldText = {foo: 'bar'};

  const currentTheme = {
      BoldText: {
        color: 'black' 
         },
        text:{ ...BoldText }
       }
```